# General integer variables in the MPS format

Tags: mps

Is it possible to specify an integer-constrained variable without any bounds in the MPS format?

I am reading

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.0?topic=extensions-integer-variables-in-mps-files

and cannot figure out the way to do it.

Also the previously mentioned documentation states:

To specify a general integer variable with no upper bounds, one must use the first way, that is, make certain that the variable's column is described within an INTORG/INTEND marker pair.

I thought the bound key LI is used to specify an integer-constrained variable with no upper bound.

Comment: maybe you can try to write FR Bound     x1 for your general integer without any bounds. Is it your question asking?

Comment: To me it seems like a guess. Do you know whether that works? And what should I do more than FR to make the variable integer-constrained?

Comment: I tried pyscipopt, I created two general integer variables without bounds (x, y), and introduced the constraint (x+y=1) to test out, then it works, without any objective function since that would lead problem become unbounded.

Comment: LI specifies a lower bound for an integer variable and leaves it to you to specify the upper bound with a separate UB line. I'm not sure what happens if you omit the UB line. In any case, you could pecify the smallest and largest possible values (-2^31, 2^31 - 1) as bounds.

Comment: But what if the integer variable is not in the INTORG/INTEND section, then there is no upper bound. I would assume LI just imposed a lower bound and make the variable integer. That is what confuses me about LI.

Answer (score 0):

I used Gurobi to write out the following ILP in mps format:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min & 0 \\
s.t. & x + y = 1 \\
& x \geq 0 \\
& y \text{ free} \\
& x,y \text{ integer}
\end{array}
$$

The corresponding result is:

```
NAME 
ROWS
 N  OBJ
 E  R0      
COLUMNS
    MARKER    'MARKER'                 'INTORG'
    C0        R0        1
    C1        R0        1
    MARKER    'MARKER'                 'INTEND'
RHS
    RHS1      R0        1
BOUNDS
 LI BND1      C0        0
 FR BND1      C1      
ENDATA
```

So it seems that using `FR` is the bound key here.

Comment: Putting C0 within INTORD/INTEND should be redundant. The LI key should make C0 integer constrained I would assume.